# Why does my Editor (Emacs) always create 3 seperate files?

Tags: editor

I guess this is a very simple answer and I just wanted a quick reply. So why does python programs create 3 files? For example I have 3 files named:

"ReadSchedule.py"

"ReadSchedule.py~"

"#ReadSchedule.py#"

What is the reason for this? Are each file doing its own thing?

Comment: Python does not create these.

Comment: -1: This is not a Python question at all.  Please fix the tags and title.

Comment: Yes sir! I only learned that now sorry!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are temporary files created by your editor(s). The `ReadSchedule.py` file is the real one; the others can be deleted.

Comment: Your editor is making backups (`ReadSchedule.py`) and temporary files (`#ReadSchedule.py#`). Using `ls --ignore-backups` will hide the backups.

Comment: Let your editor keep backups, by the way.  Disk space is cheap.  :)

Comment: Don't attempt to delete temporary files; it probably won't work, and if it does, it could cause problems for your editor. The file should disappear automatically when you close the editor.